# /src: error: could not find source files for target(s): MyKituraAppTests; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path

Tags: swift4, swift-package-manager, kitura

I'm trying to compile using `swift build`

**Package.swift**

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

// swift-tools-version:x.x
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyKituraApp",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura", from: "2.7.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyKituraApp",
            dependencies: ["Kitura"],
            path: "Sources"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyKituraAppTests",
            dependencies: ["MyKituraApp"],
            path: "Test")
    ]
)
```

But, I get the following error although I did add the path property.

> 'MyKituraApp' /src: **error**: could not find source files for target(s): MyKituraAppTests; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your project structure I can't give you a definite answer but I'll do my best!

I'm going to assume you've generated your project using the Swift Package Manager tool, something like this: 
`swift package init --type executable`

So... Typically you shouldn't need to set the `path` property unless you've moved the tests for your application to another directory. The Swift Package Manager, by default, will create a `Tests` directory and when you do not provide a value for the `path` property the Swift Package Manager will look for that `Tests` directory by default when you run `swift build`. In your `path` property you are providing a value of `Test` not `Tests`

So my first solution to test would be:
To remove the `path` property from the `.testTarget` section

OR

Rename the `path` properties value to `Tests` rather than `Test`.

I've provided an example Package.swift that I was able to run `swift build` with:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyKituraApp",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura", from: "2.7.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyKituraApp",
            dependencies: ["Kitura"],
            path: "Sources"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyKituraAppTests",
            dependencies: ["MyKituraApp"])
    ]
)
```

As you can see I've also removed an extra line from the top of the file:
`// swift-tools-version:x.x`

You've already provided a `swift-tools-version` at the top of your file, this line may end up confusing things later down the line.

I hope this helps!